# There was an error communicating with AWS Step Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I was trying to play around with AWS Step functions following the instructions specified in the document(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/getting-started.html).
While trying to create a state machine, I got the following error message. 
**"There was an error communicating with AWS Step Functions, please try again later."**

I am executing step functions in the region **EU Ireland**.
I created a role by following the instructions mentioned in the link( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/procedure-create-iam-role.html). Also tried to update the Role definition with policy " AdministratorAccess" assuming the role doesn't have required permission to create state machine, which didn't help either.

Could you help me with this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue. It is a bit of a strange error message, but for me the issue was that my user did not have permissions to create a step function.

Comment: @Semi : Yes, it was the same issue for me as well. The error message doesn't help at all. If you try to create state machine through "Sample Projects" example,  you get more information on the error message at "Create State machine" step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with IAM permissions for the account using Step functions. Adding the policies mentioned in the document(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concept-create-iam-advanced.html) lets you create step functions.